# How to return a string value in a JTextField?

Tags: java, web-services

I have this code below and I want to return the string value to the JTextField. And it doesn't work.

```
String numar= numartxt.getText().trim();
int aa;
aa = Integer.parseInt(numar);
try {
   mypack.ParImpar_Service service = new mypack.ParImpar_Service();
   mypack.ParImpar port = service.getParImparPort();
   // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
   int val=aa;
   // TODO process result here
   java.lang.String result = port.operation(aa);
   rezultattxt.setText(result);
}
```

Where `rezultattxt` is my JTextField.

Comment: Are you sure the program doesn't crash before it reaches this line? Since it's in a `try` block, it it crashes before the last line, it'll go to the `catch` block (Will skip that line).

Comment: It's not clear what thread is executing this code - however, you should be manipulating Swing components only within the Event Dispatch Thread, and _not_ doing long running operations like a web service call from the EDT.